# How to Deploy new version of application in auto scale GCP environment

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deployment, autoscaling, cicd

i am working on usecase where we are having a auto-scaling environment inside google cloud platform the thing is that right now i don't know how to deploy new version of application in GCP auto scaling environment the code is on github.

previously it was getting deploy through jenkins but since we have configure auto-scaling so its impossible to deploy via jenkins can anyone help me with this ?

I was thinking that we should configure a new VM image each time and deploy it by adding that image to the new instace group but it is quite complicated

Comment: Which autoscale environment do you use? A managed instance group? Serverless product? Kubernetes replicas?

Comment: its a managed instance group

Comment: Ok, you simply have to create a new instance template and to perform a roll out over your managed instance group

Answer (score 0):

As @guillaume blaquiere suggested,you have to create a new instance template and to perform a roll out over your managed instance group

To [create a new instance template](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates/create-instance-templates) follow the steps below:

1. In the Google Cloud console, go to the Instance templates page.
2. Click Create instance template.
3. Enter values for the following fields, or accept the default values. The default values change based on the machine family that you select.
4. Click Create to create the template.

Also refer this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/rolling-out-updates-to-managed-instance-groups#:%7E:text=In%20the%20Google%20Cloud%20console%2C%20go%20to%20the%20Instance%20groups%20page.,-Go%20to%20Instance&text=Select%20the%20managed%20instance%20group,template%20to%20all%20your%20instances.) for more information